# jQuery - add element inside element but not wrap the text

Tags: jquery

I want to add a `<span>` element inside `<label>` with jQuery:

```
jQuery('.custom-checkbox2 label').wrapInner('<span class="circle"></span>');
```

This is a default state:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chcb">
    <label for="chcb">Text</label>
</div>
```

This is what I want:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chcb">
    <label for="chcb">
        <span class="circle"></span>Text
    </label>
</div>
```

And this result I'm getting:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chcb">
    <label for="chcb">
        <span class="circle">Text</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for: [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

So in your case instead of `.wrapInner('<span class="circle"></span>')`
You use `.prepend('<span class="circle"></span>')`